# Why is the computation of the general $p$-norm hard?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, symmetric-matrices, matrix-analysis

Consider a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Can we find a general polynomial for computing the operator norm induced by a $p$-norm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The norm of the matrix $\pmatrix{a & b\cr c & d\cr}$ is the maximum of
$(|a x + b y|^p + |c x + d y|^p)^{1/p}$ subject to the constraint $|x|^p + |y|^p = 1$.
Using a Lagrange multiplier, we would consider
$$F(x,y,\lambda) = |ax+by|^p + |cx+dy|^p + \lambda(|x|^p + |y|^p - 1)$$
take the derivatives with respect to $x$, $y$ and $\lambda$, and solve.
If $p$ is rational, the results will involve algebraic functions of $a,b,c,d$, but 
are likely to be very complicated. For example, in the case $p=4$, $x$ will be a root of
a polynomial of degree $24$ with coefficients polynomials in $a,b,c,d$, with $340$ terms when expanded.
If $p$ is irrational, I don't see how they could be
algebraic functions in general.